# Texmaker open session on start?

Tags: texmaker

I have installed Texmaker 4.1 and use the save session functionality as I like to recover my definition of a master document and open all the files at once.

Is there any way to configure that Texmaker would start the most recent session automatically and focus on the file I was working last (this cannot be saved in the session)? I already know of the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+F8.

Comment: the feature had been requested a while ago:
https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1225